# Xpath query to take nth occurrence from last occurrence

Tags: xpath, xquery

How to take last 3rd occurrence in xpath for below xml.

When I try with below query it not works. Expected to be **Last Third Occurence**

Xpath I tried:

```
/LINK/TEST[last(3)]/NAME
```

XML:

```
<LINK>
  <N_Number_of_TESTs>
    <NAME>N_Number_of_Names</NAME>
  </N_Number_of_TESTs>
  <TEST>
    <NAME>Last Third Occurence</NAME>
  </TEST>
  <TEST>
    <NAME>Last Second Occurence</NAME>
  </TEST>
  <TEST>
    <NAME>Last Occurence</NAME>
  </TEST>
</LINK>
```

Comment: Did you get the idea of using `last(3)` from some documentation, or was it just a wild guess? What made you expect that it would give you the third last occurrence? It looks to me like a completely wild guess, and guessing isn't going to get you very far with XPath or with any other language.

Comment: No. This is just for comparison. If we add 3 records that will be added in last. That's why we need to compare first incoming with last 3rd XML occurrence and 3rd incoming with last XML occurrence like that. So I need this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `/LINK/TEST[last() - 2]/NAME`.

Comment: And likely to be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The following will select the third-from-last `TEST` element:

```
//TEST[count(following-sibling::TEST)=2]
```

Comment: This will work but it's likely to be VERY inefficient on a large document (though it depends on the processor, of course)